# Setting minimum and maximum date on Calendar?

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, date, calendar

I've had a look around, once again and can't find how to set the minimum and maximum dates allowed to be selected on a calendar in ASP.net with VB.

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and it's just a regular Calendar control at the moment...

At the moment I've seen things like:

```
Calendar1.DateMin = DateTime.Now
```

But Visual Basic doesn't seem to like that (maybe it's a C# thing?)... Anyway, if there's a way to do this it'll be a great help!

Comment: "VB doesn't seem to like that" isn't an error description. What error are you experiencing?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.monthcalendar.mindate%28v=vs.71%29.aspx ??

Comment: @huMptyduMpty: Your link is  for Winforms not ASP.NET.

Comment: To clarify on this, DateMin doesn't exist in visual basic in that form by itself at least.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to handle the Calendar's [`DayRender`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.calendar.dayrender.aspx) event:

```
Private MinDate As Date = Date.MinValue
Private MaxDate As Date = Date.MaxValue

Protected Sub Calendar1_DayRender(sender As Object, e As DayRenderEventArgs)Handles Calendar1.DayRender
    If e.Day.Date < MinDate OrElse e.Day.Date > MaxDate Then
        e.Day.IsSelectable = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Then you can set it for example in `Page_Load`:

```
MinDate = Date.Today
MaxDate = MinDate.AddDays(7)
```