# asp.net calendar date range

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, calendar

I have two calendars. What I am trying to implement is based on the date selected in the first calendar, the date range in the second one will be from `calendar1.selectedDate + 1` until indefinite.

So any of the `dates < calendar1.selectedDate` should not be selectable in `calendar2`.

How to set a range for a calendar, or at least set the start date?

`asp:calendar` has many attributes but just cannot find what I am looking for.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This link it should solve your issue.

[Tweak the answer provided by Tim Schmelter in this link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10227417/setting-minimum-and-maximum-date-on-calendar

Comment: @ComputerGeek learn markdown for comments [TEXT](WEBSITE)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Try this**

For the second calendar control

```
<asp:Calendar ID="Calendar2" runat="server" ondayrender="Calendar2_DayRender"></asp:Calendar>
```

on *DayRender* event

```
    protected void Calendar2_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime dte = Calendar1.SelectedDate;
        if (e.Day.Date <= dte)
        {
            e.Day.IsSelectable = false;
            e.Cell.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gray;
        }
    }
```