# how to select only current and upcoming dates in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using calendar control in asp.net. When the user select the date it will be displayed in the textbox. This is the code that I used for that:

```
protected void Calendar1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox1.Text = Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToString("dd/MM/yy");

    }
```

But I want to make only the current and upcoming dates to be selectable. When the user select the past date, I want to display a error message. How can I do this?

Comment: Related: [Setting minimum and maximum date on Calendar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10227417/setting-minimum-and-maximum-date-on-calendar)

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle [`DayRender`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.calendar.dayrender(v=vs.110).aspx) event.

**ASPX:**

```
<asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server" ondayrender="Calendar1_DayRender"> </asp:Calendar>
```

**CodeBehind :** disable's past days

```
  protected void Calendar1_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
  {
        if (e.Day.Date.CompareTo(DateTime.Today) < 0)
        {
            e.Day.IsSelectable = false;
        }
  }
```